# How to provide SSL to APIs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ssl, express

I used self signed openssl for APIs but when they are used client side it is showing the error message `in secured response`. How to provide original ssl cert? And I'm using elastic bean stalk in aws to host APIs. In that I have come across ACM and that is integrated with Elastic Load Balancing and Amazon CloudFront. So which one should I use from those two? If I use any of those two, will that be enough in production mode? Or should I use any other one?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a certificate with ACM that matches your DNS record. Then point that DNS record to your Elastic Beanstalk Environments DNS record. Which will be something like `ENV-name.76p5XXXX22.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com`

AWS has a document you can follow [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html).

Comment: After creating the certificate using ACM, I followed the link you mentioned. In my `env` I just added ssl certificate from drop down in `configuration` in `network tier`. But still I'm getting insecure data. Is there still anything to do?

Comment: Did you point the DNS record at the EB env? What's the domain?

Comment: No, I didn't do it. Can you tell me the steps how to do it or any link?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-beanstalk-environment.html

Comment: I will tell you what I have done till now, please tell me if I'm wrong anywhere, because when I open my EBS URL in browser I'm still getting broken HTTPS symbol in red color. My Client is hosted at say www.example.com. My server code is hosted at EBS in AWS. I got cert through ACM by giving domain name example.com in it. I have set this ssl id in configuration of my EBS ENV. Now I created hosted zone as example.com(both NS and SOA got created when I created it) and Record Set NAME as app.example.com, TYPE as CNAME, ALIAS as No, VALUE as my EBS ENV URL, ROUTING as simple in ROUTE 53.

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin.

For development purposes, self signed certificate is okay. You can set `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` in environment variables.

For AWS Elastic Beanstalk behind Load Balancer, you can have 2 ways -

1. **One way encrypted** - In this you add a certificate in your load balancer only. This way, Client to Load balancer is encrypted and then load balancer to instances is unencrypted. This is safe. I use this. This way I don't have to use any certificates on my instances and I run a normal HTTP server on instances. You can choose to allow only HTTPS or not from load balancer settings.
2. **End to end encrypted** - In this you use a certificate on your instances as well and you can choose to forward encrypted traffic directly from Load Balancer to your instances or you can decrypt and re-encrypt traffic and send to instances. I don't have any experience with this. The first option is suitable for most cases. Refer to this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-endtoend.html